# Modify the "size" of geom_link function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, segment, geom

This is the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(60,69,50), y=c(0,14,75), x2=c(80,78,75), y2= c(72,10,92))
```

and this the code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_link(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x2, yend = y2, alpha = 0.1, size = stat(index)), lineend = "round")
```

I want to modify the size of `geom_link` but I didn't figure out how

[image]

Comment: What are you wanting to change, you have a size call in geom_link that seems to change the size?

Comment: If I change it to size=1 for example it doesn't work... I want to modify the thickness of the segments and keeping the same shape

Comment: Using `I`  seems to do the trick e.g. `size = stat(I(10*index)))` ; change `10` to suit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user20650 Thank you that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @HamzaFerchichi ; your welcome,  although not quite exact as it removes the legend.